# Discrepancy in Calculating Expectation of a Dependent Random Variable

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

Suppose $X$ a is random variable with pdf $$\begin{cases} f(x), & x\ge 0 \\ 0, & x\lt 0 \end{cases} $$ The random variable $Y$ is defined as $$Y= \begin{cases} A, & X\lt k \\ A+BX, & X\ge k \end{cases} $$ where $A,B,k$ are positive constants. If I’m not wrong, the pdf of $Y$ is then $$ \begin{cases} \int_0^k f(x) dx, & y=A \\ f\left(\frac{y-A}{B}\right), & y\gt A \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
as the first case corresponds to $P(X\lt k)$ and the second case corresponds to $P\left(X=\frac{y-A}{B} \right)$, and so $$E(Y)=A\int_0^k f(x) dx \ + \int_A^{\infty} yf\left(\frac{y-A}{B} \right) dy $$

But at the same time, I could also look at this expectation as $$E(Y) = A + B\int_k^{\infty} xf(x) dx $$ as $Y$ will always be a certain amount more than $A$, which depends on $X$.

Which of the two is the correct expression? Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods lead exactly to the same expectation.

Your second expression is

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
\mathbb{E}(Y)=A+B\int_k^{\infty} xf_X(x)dx
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

and it is correct!

For the first case, the rv is not absolutely continuous anyway we can derive its CDF (that always exists) in the following way:

$$ F_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $y<A$ } \\
\int_0^k f_X(x)dx,  & \text{if $y=A$ } \\
F_X\left(\frac{y-A}{B}\right), & \text{if $y\geq A+Bk$}
\end{cases}$$

Thus the expectation is

$$\mathbb{E}(Y)=A\int_0^kf_X(x)dx+\int_{A+Bk}^{\infty}\frac{1}{B}yf_X\left(\frac{y-A}{B}\right)dy$$

Now substitute $\frac{y-A}{B}=x$ and get

$$\mathbb{E}(Y)=A\int_0^kf_X(x)dx+\int_{k}^{\infty}(A+Bx)f_X(x)dx$$

Which is the same as (1)

---

Here is an useful drawing

[image]

As you can see,  Y-domain is X-image thus

$$Y \in A \cup [A+Bk;\infty)$$

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Shouldn’t the third case in the cdf of $Y$ be $y\gt A$? Right now the domain is not $\mathbb R$. 2) Does the pdf not exist then? What if I differentiate the cdf w.r.t $y$?

Comment: @Tavish : 1) in case 3 writing $>$ or $\geq$ is the same as $F_X(0)=0$. 2) if you differentiate wrt y in that interval it's ok

Comment: @Tavish: actually although the pdf does not exist one can derive a "mixed pdf" which is discrete in $Y=A$ and continuous elsewhere.

Comment: But you wrote $y\ge A+ Bk$, not $y\ge A$.

Comment: @Tavish : I have been a little cryptic but I was answering with the cell phone. Now I edited my answer with an useful drawing. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies things.

Answer (score 1):

We can write:$$Y=A+BX1_{[k,\infty)}(X)$$

Then:$$\mathbb EY=\mathbb E\left[A+BX1_{[k,\infty)}(X)\right]=A+B\mathbb EX1_{[k,\infty)}(X)=A+B\int_k^{\infty}xf(x)dx$$

In cases like this it is not handsome to figure out what the PDF (if it exists) of $Y$ looks like.

Actually it is possible here that $Y$ does not even have a PDF. For that note that $P(Y=A)$ might well be  positive. If so then $Y$ is not a continuous random variable (hence has no PDF).

Comment: But surely $Y$ has a pdf for $Y\gt A$, right? I’ve noticed that in my first expression, the first term comes from treating $Y$ as discrete while the second comes from treating it as continuous.

Comment: If $P(Y=c)>0$ for some $c$ then $Y$ has no [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). You can at most split up $Y$ as $Y=Y_1+Y_2$ where one of the $Y_i$ is discrete and the other has a PDF.